# Tablesorter sort multiple dollar signs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I want to use tablesorter to sort a column of table cells with a number of dollar signs in them. The amount of dollar signs will range from one $ to five $$$$$, and should sort with 1 being the lowest and 5 being the highest. Note: I need these strings to be matched exactly because there will be many dollar signs being thrown around, so $$$ needs to be differentiated from $$, and $.

Here is the code I'm currently using, it does NOT work when I have the dollar signs in, however when I replace them with "b" and "a", it works perfectly. I have 2 dollar signs representing 1 because I read that this is necessary to represent the dollar symbol in a regex. I've also tried `\$`. Could this be caused by the way the dollar signs are entered in the HTML table? I've used both the standard "$", and "`&#36;`", neither work correctly.

```
   // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
    $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'pricerange', 
        is: function(s) { 
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return false; 
        }, 
        format: function(s) { 
            // format your data for normalization 
            return s.toLowerCase().replace(/\bd\b/g,3).replace(/\bc\b/g,2).replace(/\b$$$$\b/g,1).replace(/\b$$\b/g,0); 
        }, 
        // set type, either numeric or text 
        type: 'numeric' 
    }); 

    $(function() { 
        $("myTable").tablesorter({ 
            headers: { 
                3: { 
                    sorter:'pricerange' 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return s.match(/\$/g).length;
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but unfortunately it didn't. I also tried: `s.replace(/\$/g,0)` and `s.replace(/\b\$\b/g,0)` and `s.replace(/$$/g,0)` just in case. Nothing is working, and I'm very confused as to why.

Comment: Are they genuine "$" symbols, or "&#36;" character entities? Are they contiguous (no whitespace in between)? Are you applying the parser to the correct column?

Comment: You also need to adjust the selector in `$("myTable")`, eg `$("#myTable")`.

Comment: Thanks for that @Mottie. Please may I have the yacht?

Comment: Even simpler, if the column entries are only ever "$" strings with no prefix or suffix, then `return s.length;` will do the job. Thus you could use "$" strings or any other single-character currency symbol - Euro, Pound, Yen etc.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I'm sure I could get you [this one](http://www.cargolaw.com/images/disaster2007.crane-yacht14.GIF) cheap!

Comment: Thanks very much. I've figured out that for some reason my problem stemmed from my inclusion of this snippet of javascript 
`<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
 ); 
 </script>` 
I'm not sure where I saw that, but I must have seen that suggested somewhere and included it erroneously. After I removed that and removed the table name (id="myTable") it worked like a charm.

Thanks very much for all of your help! Apparently I require 15 rep to upvote you, but I'll come back when I have them and do it!